# How do I clear Flutter's image cache?

Tags: dart, flutter

[Flutter](https://flutter.io) has its own internal cache of images. I need to clear that image cache. How do I do that?

Comment: wow, using SO as an online doc is a great idea

Comment: Is it?! I think its better to keep this site as it intended to use. If you want a FAQ make a FAQ, if you want a documentation write a documentation. I want my documentation in my IDE not in SO...
I don't think pumped up questions would make this site better. I want questions from the developers that uses the language and answers from the guys that making it. 

If there is a question thats shows up many times or got more upvotes maybe there is some problem with their product or their documentation that should be fixed...

Comment: I am lacking the ability to distinguish sarcasm / trolling from serious answers. I just hope the first answer is sarcasm and the second one mistakenly interpreted it as serious.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Refer to the [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageCache-class.html)

```
/// This is the custom implementation of [ImageCache] where we can override
/// the logic.
class MyImageCache extends ImageCache {
  @override
  void clear() {
    print('Clearing cache!');
    super.clear();
  }
}

class MyWidgetsBinding extends WidgetsFlutterBinding {
  @override
  ImageCache createImageCache() => MyImageCache();
}

void main() {
  // The constructor sets global variables.
  MyWidgetsBinding();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: why not exposing that under flutter doctor ?

Comment: Since the answer is also edited by Seth, it looked for a second like he also answered it. Since 3 out of 4 questions I look at on SO lately are Seth's I'd say the strategy is working. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

in my case I used another solution:

Add key value to image widget: `Image(key: UniqueKey(), image: FileImage(File(path))))`

Add two lines in your image page, if you need clear cache once, so put it in initState() or if you need to clear cache every time after setState() for example, so you can put in build method:

```
imageCache.clear();
imageCache.clearLiveImages();
```

Comment: The docs state "The cache is used internally by ImageProvider and should generally not be accessed directly.". I'm not sure if any side effects occur. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/imageCache.html