# Flutter - Image remains after being deleted?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am experiencing some weird behavior around images in flutter.

I am using the [camera](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera) package to capture images like so:

```
void _takePicture() {
_controller.takePicture(_tempImagePath).then((_) {
  setState(() {
    _captured = true;
    _shutterButtonController.forward();
    _acceptCancelController.forward();
  });
});
}
```

Pretty straightforward - the image is captured how I expect. If you notice the `_captured` member, I am using this to drive display of either the camera preview, or the captured image. Here is a snippet of my widget tree:

```
...
AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: _captured
            ? Image.file(File(_tempImagePath))
            : CameraPreview(_controller)),
...
```

This also behaves like I expect - the image is displayed after being captured. However, the catch appears to be that `Image.file(...)` will always display the same image. I have tried a number of ways to delete this image, and I believe it is working, yet the image somehow persists.

I'm at the point where I am deleting & recreating the entire directory inside of `initState()` as the screen is constructed like so:

```
Future<String> get getTempImageDirectory async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  var imageDirectory = Directory(directory.path + '/images/');

  print('The image directory ${imageDirectory.path} exists: ${imageDirectory.existsSync()}');

  if (imageDirectory.existsSync()) {
    imageDirectory.deleteSync(recursive: true);
  }

  imageDirectory.createSync();

  return imageDirectory.path;
}
```

Even with this, or deleting the images manually by name, the originally captured image persists inside of the Widget created by `Image.file(...)`. I am fairly certain that the delete is working fine - the camera API will throw an error that it cannot overwrite the previous image if you *don't* delete it.

Finally, if I kill the app and restart, I will be able to retake the picture and see a new one, but again, that one will remain until the whole application is killed. It seems like the image is somehow cached?

I'm fairly new to Flutter and Dart, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: As far as I get it you need to setState the bool _captured back to false.

Comment: `_captured` gets set to false as part of a cancellation flow, but didn't really seem relevant to post. The UI switches back and forth between the camera preview and the Image appropriately, just the image doesn't update with the newest result from the camera.

Comment: I guess you need to share more of the code. It could be that _tempImagePath isn't updated appropiately. Did you call that with setState?

Comment: Nope, I am pretty sure all of that is right  / not relevant, which is why it isn't included. I've posted the solution below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After searching through Github issues, I was able to learn that Flutter is [caching](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ImageCache-class.html) these images behind the scenes. They'll persist in-memory regardless of being deleted from disk.

I added this to my delete method, and my problem was solved.

```
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
...
imageCache.clear();
```

I've also found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209606/how-do-i-clear-flutters-image-cache), however the import statement appears to be wrong based on Flutter v0.5.1.

Comment: **imageCache.clear()** didn't work for me. **PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear()** did the trick.

Comment: Will it just clear the cached images taken by camera or all the cached images? (I've some cached images from firestore as well).

Answer (score 1):

in my case, need to clear live images too. And if your image is in ListView set Image key as UniqueKey().

```
imageCache.clearLiveImages();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these two lines to clear the cache:

```
  imageCache!.clearLiveImages();
  imageCache!.clear();
```

in my case it didn't worked with **imageCache.clear()**, so i had to clear live images too