# image_picker saves selected images to cache folder

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I am using  image_picker: ^0.6.7+7  to select files from Gallery. when select image >> Image picker saves image automatically to cache folder. this makes high storage usage.
Question : how not to saved file to storage,

my code ::

```
var picker = ImagePicker();
picker
// .getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality:100,maxHeight: 200,maxWidth: 200)
.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 30)
.then((PickedFile image) {
callbackPicker(image);
});
```

Comment: Might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209606/how-do-i-clear-flutters-image-cache

Comment: Hi Scott. ImagePicker will copy any selected image to application cache folder, i do not know why. I think clearImageCache clears memory data. But in ImagePicker case, it copies it into storage. I need to  let ImagePicker not copy images to storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to remove the temporary file, is to remove the reference to it.  Kind of like this image = null.  If you need to use the image in other parts of your app, then load it into memory before nullify out the image file reference.

Comment: Iam using below code. how to adapt :       var picker = ImagePicker();
    picker
    
        .getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 30)
        .then((PickedFile image) {
      callbackPicker(image);
    });

Comment: Yes, it will save to a cache at first.  It does this, because devices have more disk space than memory.   It's a temporary storage until you use it or dispose of it.  Just make sure you dispose of the images when not in use.