# How to prevent caching images from network flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I have tried all of the following `Widget` to load images from network :

- `Image.network()`
- `CachedNetworkImage()`

And also their `ImageProvider` :

- `NetworkImage`
- `CachedNetworkImageProvider`

There is no `bool` to choose not to cache images. The only way i have found is to load the `ImageProvider` like in `initState()` and then call `evict()` right after.

I don't really know if this works actually or if this is the best way to do...

Is there any way to prevent caching from network "natively" ?

Comment: Image.network() does not cache the image. it downloads it again every time u go to widget.

Comment: from the documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html : ```All network images are cached regardless of HTTP headers.```. 
Am i not understanding this sentence correctly ?

Comment: I guess you are right. reference here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209606/how-do-i-clear-flutters-image-cache I think this is your answer

Comment: thank you for the link, but does it mean that every instance of ImageCache will be cleared automatically ? Meaning that everytime we load an ImageProvider it will be evicted from cache ?

Comment: Where are you testing/ web does cache automatically. But on android/ios it doesn't

Comment: Yes it is Android / IOS only. and you are right i have the output that there is no "pending" cache configuration for a given provider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just created a widget that gets the image as a URL and then download it as `Uint8List` and show it in a `Image.memory` widget.

You can use it like this:

```
NonCacheNetworkImage('https://riverpod.dev/img/logo.png'),
```

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class NonCacheNetworkImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NonCacheNetworkImage(this.imageUrl, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final String imageUrl;
  Future<Uint8List> getImageBytes() async {
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
    return response.bodyBytes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
      future: getImageBytes(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) return Image.memory(snapshot.data!);
        return SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: Text("NO DATA"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure Image.memory does not cache ? I mean I kept retrying using your method then cecking ( imageCache.currentSize ) & ( imageCache.liveImageCount ) and still gave me some values,, and need to know for certain that Image.memory does not cache to be able to check other places for my problem

Answer (score 18):

You can achieve that simply by adding `?` followed by `timestamp` at the end of your image url.

```
Image.network(
   '${imgUrl}?${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}',
   fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

Comment: darn! so clever!

Comment: It works because the URL is unique, but every url is cached anyway, you just can't fall back on the old one. My goal was to not put anything in cache so i can't accept this answer although it's useful !