# Flutter PageView progressively uses more memory

Tags: flutter, dart

In a flutter PageView containing high-resolution images, as I swipe to new images, flutter uses more and more memory. How do I fix it?

Here is my main.dart file.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final List<String> urls = [
    "https://unsplash.com/photos/Eelegt4hFNc/download?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fHwxNjc1NzA4NTgy&force=true",
    "https://unsplash.com/photos/MI9AqYWeM24/download?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fHwxNjc1NzA4Njk1&force=true",
    "https://unsplash.com/photos/kFHz9Xh3PPU/download?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fHwxNjc1NzA3NDU3&force=true",
    "https://unsplash.com/photos/_AjqGGafofE/download?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fHwxNjc1Njg0MDMx&force=true",
    "https://unsplash.com/photos/8Qr1ixi-rMU/download?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fHwxNjc1NzA0NTkx&force=true",
    "https://unsplash.com/photos/xaZSE0h7yIY/download?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fHwxNjc1NzA4MTY1&force=true",
    "https://unsplash.com/photos/RbRWDUyDEWQ/download?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fHwxNjc1NzA4NzY5&force=true",
    "https://unsplash.com/photos/HJCywuQqKYY/download?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fHwxNjc1NzA4Nzcx&force=true"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
        itemCount: urls.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Image(image: NetworkImage(urls[index]));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After swiping through the images flutter uses around 1.7 GB memory.

[image: Task Manager]

Here is the memory graph

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are checking it on release mode of application?

Comment: The above screenshots are from profile mode but it also happens in release mode (increasing up to around 1.5 GB). One thing I noticed is that memory usage comes back to normal once I resize my window.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Flutter caches images. I've found that in order to avoid app termination by OOM killer, it is sometimes necessary to be more hands-on with image memory management.

In your case, you may benefit from explicitly calling the [NetworkImage.evict()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider/evict.html) method, which is inherited from `ImageProvider`.

There are other strategies, too. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237163) shows how to override the image cache. You can implement your own customizations, such as never caching more than *N* images.

See also the [ImageCache class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageCache-class.html).

It may also depend on behavior of `PageView`. I am not familiar with this widget and if/how it disposes of children which are no longer visible. If it is hanging on to [ui.Image](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) references, you may have to go to some special effort.